# How can I Replace text within a HTML tag

Tags: jquery, html

What i want to do `enter code here`is replace the H2 tags within the div with the class of `.location` using jQuery. How can i achieve this?

I want to change both of them. URL or/and Name. Either or. Thanks.

```
    <div class="location">
    <h2><a href="#">United States</a></h2>
    <h3>lorem ipsum...</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Addresss</li>
      <li>Address 2</li>
      <li>Phone: xxx</li>
      <li>Fax: xxx</li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="location">
    <h2><a href="#">Europe</a></h2>
    <h3>lorem ipsum...</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Addresss</li>
      <li>Address 2</li>
      <li>Phone: xxx</li>
      <li>Fax: xxx</li>
    </ul>
</div>



$('.location h2').replaceWith('<a href="#"><h2>Europe</h2></a>');
```

but it changes both location namess

Comment: Probably just a copy/paste error, but your `<div>`s need closing

Comment: Do you want them to both be changed to the same thing?

Comment: thanks. adusted the div @freefaller

Comment: no. @ikiar separately! different URL Strings and Names

Comment: So how should this jQuery know what to change, and what to change the text, or URL, *to*?

Comment: i just edited my question. you can see what i tried. @DavidThomas

Comment: Why was that comment aimed at me, you haven't answered my question? That, I think, should have been @j08691. My question, however, still stands: how should the jQuery know what to act on, and how to act on it? And could you show the expected *output* from this script? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: no..@iKiar I'm trying to use the `eq` maybe that would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up doing this to answer my own question.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.location:eq(0) h2:first').replaceWith('<h2><a href="someurl.com">USA</a></h2>');
    $('.location:eq(0) h3:eq(1)').replaceWith('<h3>Test</h3></a>');
    $('.location:eq(1) h2:first').replaceWith('<h2><a href="someurl.com">CAN</a></h2>');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_values_arr = ['one', 'two'];
$('.location h2').each(function(index, element){
    element.replaceWith(new_values_arr[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use html method.

In your case :

```
 $('.location h2').html('<a href="#"><h2>Europe</h2></a>');
```

This will change the html of h2 tag.

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheks/AxM54/)